# Subcommand utility in Haskell

Tags: command-line, haskell

Is there a simple recipe or library for creating a subcommand command line utility in Haskell?

E.g. `git log` for logging, `git status` for status et cetera. Something like [Python's argparse's support for subcommands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) would be fantastic.

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used it myself yet, but take a look at the [CmdArgs](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/cmdargs/) package.

Comment: This is looking really good... the documentation is seriously lacking unfortunately. Off to read blog posts, I guess.

Comment: Found a very helpful blog post: http://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/haskell-using-cmdargs-single-and-multi-mode Looks good!

Comment: Nice blog post! Thanks for mentioning it here as well.

Comment: @vicvicvic - I've always found the cmdargs documentation very helpful (for the implicit version, the explicit functions are under-documented).  Are you looking at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.6.9/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html)?  Just look for `args` and you see `cmdargs` (easy to use, arguably the most popular solution), `parseargs` (less magic, might actually work with a non-GHC compiler, also easy to use), and `simpleargs` (I've not used this one).  Others are probably out there, but you should look at the haddock documents and decide which one seems most fitting for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Write one simple main application that only checks for its first argument string, and delecates basing on that. It will pass the subsequent arguments to the program that actually handles the requests (the `log` or `status`). Group common functionality in modules to be available and you already have a tidy framework to write new "modules" as they sometimes are called.

Comment: Well sure, but I was hoping there were something library like with more features (--help, listing subcommands etc).

Comment: @vicvicvic: I see! Sorry, haven't used such libraries.